# Angular: date format YYYY-MM-DDth:mm:ss.sssz+ZZ:ZZ displaying with moment().format()?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, date, momentjs

I would like to display an array of dates having the following format: `YYYY-MM-DDth:mm:ss.sssz+ZZ:ZZ`.

For example: `2022-10-20T14:25:00.016Z+03:00 as DD.MM.YYYY` and `hh:mm` seperatly.

For this I'm using the `moment.format()` method. Currently my code looks like this:

```
console.log(moment('2022-10-21T12:25:00.016Z+03:00').format('DD.MM.YYYY'));
console.log(moment('2022-10-21T12:25:00.016Z+03:00').format('hh:mm'));
```

But for that I get the "invalid date" error in the console. Using this format it works:

```
console.log(moment('2022-10-21T12:25:00.016Z').format('DD.MM.YYYY'));
console.log(moment('2022-10-21T12:25:00.016Z').format('hh:mm'));
```

Is there a way to get the first version working?

Comment: How you are getting this format? it is even not working with new Date('2022-10-21T12:25:00.016Z+03:00'), so for sure it will not work with moment.

Comment: You know [there's a pipe for that](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide moment the format in order to pars it correctly

```
moment('{your time string}','{format}')
```

Like: `moment("2010-10-20 4:30 +0000", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z"); // parsed as 4:30 UTC`

You can see more about the format and how to use it in the docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/